# Angular-Toaster not working in my service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have got to know toaster.js from this [site](http://bitoftech.net/2014/01/13/building-spa-using-angularjs-example-part-3/) and trying to implement it in my web app. I have done it according to the example but it doesn't work.

Here is my service where I Implemented:

```
function () {

    angular
        .module('FoursquareApp')
        .factory('DataService', DataService);
    DataService.$inject = ['$http','toaster'];

    function DataService($http, toaster) {

        .id,
                venueName: venue.name,var serviceBase = '/api/places/';
        var placesDataFactory = {};
        var userInContext = null;

        var _getUserInCtx = function () {
            return userInContext;
        };

        var _setUserInCtx = function (userInCtx) {
            userInContext = userInCtx;
        };

        var _savePlace = function (venue) {
            //process venue to take needed properties

            var minVenue = {
                userName: userInContext,
                venueID: venue
                address: venue.location.address,
                category: venue.categories[0].shortName,
                rating: venue.rating
            };

            return $http.post(serviceBase, minVenue).then(
                function (results) {
                    toaster.pop('success', "Bookmarked Successfully", "Place saved to your bookmark!");
                },
                function (results) {
                    if (results.status == 304) {
                        toaster.pop('note', "Faield to Bookmark", "Something went wrong while saving :-(");
                    }
                    else {
                        toaster.pop('error', "Failed to Bookmark", "Something went wrong while saving :-(");
                    }

                    return results;
                });
        };
```

I have called the library scripts in index.html and also the css files.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You could post the url to the example you're following, so others can understand what you're referring to.

Comment: @DrCox I have added the url. Thanks for pointing on that

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: `Unknown provider: toasterProvider <- toaster <- DataServiceG/<@http://localhost:53761/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416eb/r.$... class="ng-scope" data-ng-view="">` This is the error it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you use `toaster.js` library? The popular one is `toastr.js`

Try to modify your code to

```
DataService.$inject = ['$http','toastr'];

function DataService($http, toastr) {
...
```

Also ensure, that you link this js file in you index.html and also refer this package in main app module definition as a second (dependency) parameter

Comment: That didn't work still the same error. Says toastProvider unkown

Comment: So ensure, that you link this js file in you `index.html` and also refer this package in main app module definition as a second (dependency) parameter

Comment: Thanks it worked forgot to add the parameter. Thanks! :)